# What is the meaning of "Won't Tell" by Babes in Toyland?

Tags: song-lyrics, interpretation, babes-in-toyland

Babes In Toyland has long been one of my favorite rock bands for the raw power of the music and vocals, but I've always felt as though there is a complexity to the lyrics of "[Won't Tell](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CwksFza7T2o&list=RDtWZ9ihZ_TUw&index=5)", compared to, say, "[Bruise Violet](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWZ9ihZ_TUw)".  Even the simple phrase "Figure out your problem with me is you" is kind of a mind-bender.

Here are the lyrics:

> I won't ever tell on you
>   Ever see me do
>   I wait forever for you
>
> Figure out your problem with me is you
>   I won't be like you
>   Ever see right through
>   I wait forever for you
>
> Figure out your problem with me is you
>   I won't ever tell on you
>   Ever see right through
>   I wait forever for you
>
> Figure out your problem with me is you
>   You come running through
>
> Figure out your problem with me is you
>   I won't ever tell
>   <sub>SOURCE: [Google Lyrics](https://play.google.com/music/preview/Thvci3mr2h3jarchxvnq7kpq6ci?lyrics=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=search&utm_campaign=lyrics&pcampaignid=kp-songlyrics)</sub>

Any thoughts or insights are appreciated, also commentary on the song by [Bjelland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kat_Bjelland).

Comment: Are you asking about the meaning of a specific part of the song or the meaning of the entire song?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Overall.  I know from Wikipedia Bjelland had major issues with an abusive stepmother, but I don't know if this song relates to that relationship or something else.

Comment: I think you should make your question more specific; it is currently at risk of getting closed because it's too broad.

Answer (score 1):

To "figure out your problem with me" is to reason out what the person's problem with the speaker is.

If the person deduces that she herself is the problem, not the speaker, it would be, as the speaker says, "you."

That is, the stepmother has blamed the problems on her stepson, but it's actually all her, and she has to work that out for herself.